# How to display output of IBM tone analyzer in pandas frame

Tags: pandas, ibm-watson, tone-analyzer

My dataset has following features: "description", "word_count", "char_count", "stopwords". The feature "description" has datatype as string which contains some text. I am doing IBM tone_analysis on this feature which gives me correct output and looks like this:

```
[{'document_tone': {'tones': [{'score': 0.677676,
     'tone_id': 'analytical',
     'tone_name': 'Analytical'}]}},
 {'document_tone': {'tones': [{'score': 0.620279,
     'tone_id': 'analytical',
     'tone_name': 'Analytical'}]}},
```

The code for above is given as below:

```
result =[]
for i in new_df['description']:
   tone_analysis = ta.tone(
       {'text': i},
     #  'application/json'
   ).get_result()
   result.append(tone_analysis)
```

I need to keep the above output in pandas data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lambda function in [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
new_df['new'] = new_df['description'].apply(lambda i: ta.tone({'text': i}).get_result())
```

EDIT:

```
def f(i):
    x = ta.tone({'text': i}).get_result()['document_tone']['tones']
    return pd.Series(x[0])


new_df = new_df.join(new_df['description'].apply(f).drop('tone_id', axis=1))
print (new_df)
```

If need also remove `description` column:

```
new_df = new_df.join(new_df.pop('description').apply(f).drop('tone_id', axis=1))
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it somehow works, the output comes in data frame with new feature as ''new' which has values as: {'document_tone': {'tones': [{'score': 0.677676,
     'tone_id': 'analytical',  'tone_name': 'Analytical'}]}}   in each row. I need output as 'score' and 'tone_name' both in two features.

Comment: The only now issue remaining is that the three new features thus created i.e.: "score", "tone_id", "tone_name" all have same values repeated, i.e.: "0.615352", "tentative", "Tentative" respectively. The values should be different inn each row.

Comment: @Akhter - If check `print(result)` it return not repeated values?

Comment: When I do print(results), the values are unique. But in pandas frame they are repeated that too it takes last row values which get repeated. The three features i.e."score", "tone_id", "tone_name" have repeated values, rest of the features are fine. I just need "score" and "tone_name", that too unique values in each row.